# Dificuldade no uso de DatePicker

Tags: java, android

Estou estudando coisas pra um projeto aqui e estou tentando usar DatePicker, consegui implementar normalmente, porem quero usar dois na mesma activity, colocando uma data inicial e uma data de final, coloquei dois botões que usam o mesmo DatePickerFragment.java, meu xml está assim:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textoData1ID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
    android:text="Data inicial"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/botaoData1ID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="118dp"
    android:text="Abrir texto inicial" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textoData2ID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="202dp"
    android:text="Data final"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/botaoData2ID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="268dp"
    android:text="Abrir data final" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textoDataFinalID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="212dp"
    android:text="Dias entre elas"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
```

Minha idéia é em cada botão abrir um DatePicker e mudar o TextView para essa data, e no final fazer a conta dos dias entres as duas datas e mostrar no terceiro TextView. Tentei usar um switch para mudar cada um um TextView, e é ai que preciso de ajuda, o que o switch vai olhar? Como diferenciar o retorno de cada botão? E como fazer a conta de quantidade de dias entre as duas data ?
Segue o codigo dos botões:

```
  botaoData1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment datePicker1 = new DatePickerFragment();
            datePicker1.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date picker");
        }
    });

    botaoData2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment datePicker2 = new DatePickerFragment();
            datePicker2.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date picker");

        }

    });
}
```

Código do DatePickerFragment:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int ano = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dia = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener)getActivity(), ano,mes,dia);
}   }
```

Comment: Esta biblioteca ja tem o Date e o Time picker, e a implementação e simples. https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

Answer (score 0):

Eu pensei na seguinte proposta:
Usar um `DatePickerDialog` em uma classe customizada que terá uma interface que devolverá um `Celendar` toda vez que o usuário finalizar a seleção da data:

#### DatePickerCalendar.java

```
public class DatePickerCalendar {
    private OnDateSetListener onDateSetListener;
    private Calendar caledarioPadrao;
    private Context contexto;

    public DatePickerCalendar(Calendar calendarioPadrao, Context context) {
        this.caledarioPadrao = calendarioPadrao;
        this.contexto = context;
        show();
    }

    public interface OnDateSetListener {
        void onDateSet(Calendar calendario);
    }

    public void setOnDateSetListener(OnDateSetListener onDateSetListener) {
        this.onDateSetListener = onDateSetListener;
    }

    private void show() {
        new DatePickerDialog(contexto, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar calendarioSelecionado = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendarioSelecionado.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
                onDateSetListener.onDateSet(calendarioSelecionado);
            }
        }, caledarioPadrao.get(Calendar.YEAR), caledarioPadrao.get(Calendar.MONTH), caledarioPadrao.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
}
```

#### Na sua Activity que contém o TextView

```
botaoData1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Calendar hoje = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerCalendar pickerCalendar = new DatePickerCalendar(hoje, MainActivity.this);
        pickerCalendar.setOnDateSetListener(new DatePickerCalendar.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(Calendar calendario) {
                TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textView11);
                tv.setText(dateMillisToString(calendario.getTimeInMillis(), "dd/MM/yyyy"));
            }
        });            
    }
});
```

#### dateMillisToString

```
private String dateMillisToString(long millis, String pattern) {
    String s = "Data desconhecida";
    try  {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.getDefault());
        s = df.format(new Date(millis));
    } catch (Exception ignored) {}
    return s;
}
```

> "E como fazer a conta de quantidade de dias entre as duas datas?"

Um dia tem 86400000 milissegundos, você pode pegar o `calendario.getTimeInMillis()`, subtrair por `calendario2.getTimeInMillis()` e multiplicar de volta por 86400000 para obter a diferença em dias